# Why is this a dangling modifier?

Tags: modifiers

The modifier here:

> Seeing the potential in data, the industry has already started to employ cognitive computing.*

Grammarly identifies *Seeing the potential in data* as a dangling modifier. However, I feel that this sentence modifies the subject. For example (the industry sees the potential in data).

Am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with *already*. The intention appears to be that the *seeing* caused the *employing*. But *already* makes it look like the *employing predates the *seeing*, leaving the first clause disconnected from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: nope. Grammarly still identifies it as a dangling modifier. I don't know why. It doesn't give any expalanation for this.

Comment: Grammarly is not capable of understanding grammar. This looks like an error on Grammarly's part

Comment: @sumelic in your opinion, would Having seen instead of seeing would be better in this context?

Comment: No; "having seen [...] has already started" doesn't seem like a natural sequence of tenses to me.

Comment: I think Grammarly is just recognizing this as a sentence pattern that usually contains a dangling modifier: *Xing the Y, Z does ...*

Comment: Here's a simple explanation of dangling modifiers: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/1/ As you can see from the examples, you can't tell whether a modifier is dangling merely from the sentence structure, you have to understand the relationships between the actions and actors in the two clauses. And Grammerly doesn't know enough to do that, so it errs on the cautious side.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think you're correct. As explained in the [Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/1/), a dangling modifier is:

> a word or phrase that modifies a word not clearly stated in the sentence.

They give this example:

> **Having finished the assignment**, the TV was turned on.

The modifier refers doesn't refer to the TV that's mentioned in the sentence, it refers to the person who turned it on.

In your example, it's clear that "seeing" refers to what the industry has done, so it's not dangling.

I believe Grammerly is merely being overly cautious, since it doesn't have enough understanding of context to tell whether "the industry" is capable of "seeing the potential in data". Perhaps when the subject of the main clause isn't a word it recognizes as an animate object (a person or animal), it assumes that this sentence structure contains a dangling modifier -- it's hard for a computer program to know when some nouns can be anthropomorphized. The designers may have a general philosophy that false positives are acceptable, because the user can easily ignore them when they know better.

Comment: And what if the transvestite was given an assignment to watch some titillating video?  Then POWL’s example isn’t dangling either!

Comment: @Jim I didn't understand what you meant, until I realized that TV could be an abbreviation for transvestite (I've never heard that use before, but maybe I don't move in the right circles).

Comment: The only transvestite I know of is Eddie Izzard.

Comment: @Jim Never heard of RuPaul?

Comment: I guess I have. But it didn’t come immediately to mind.

Comment: Probably neither of us move in the circles where we'd know of many transvestites. It also seems like the word is out of favor these days; when I tried searching for famous transvestites, Google replaced it with transgender.

Comment: I think that’s a  different concept.  The first is about how one dresses, the second is about the fundamental perception of one’s identity.

Comment: I know that. But it seems like transgender was not as acceptable or understood in the past, so many people who were actually transgender were viewed as only transvestites. I.e. they didn't come out as transgender, so all the public knew was that they dressed opposite of the gender we assumed.

Comment: This is getting way OT -- All I said was that I didn't know that "TV" was a common abbreviation for "transvestite".

Answer (score 0):

It's not. "Seeing" clearly relates to "the industry." There is nothing ambiguous about which noun the particle references. The tense, however, is a little odd given the "already" as a comment shrewdly pointed out.

"Having seen ..., the industry has already ..." or "The industry, having seen ..., has already ..."

The two sentences above show that there is nothing wrong with the placement of the participial phrase.